# MySQL query works in Workbench but not in C# code

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

SQL query:

```
SELECT som.id, som.name, som.search_enabled, oc.id, oc.name
FROM option_category oc
INNER JOIN skill_option so
    on oc.id=so.option_category_id
INNER JOIN skill_option_master som
    on som.id=so.id;
```

Works fine in Workbench:

[image]

However, within my C# code:

```
List<string> listItems = getMultiColumnListFromDB(

                         "SELECT som.id, som.name, som.search_enabled, oc.id, oc.name " +
                         "FROM option_category oc " +
                         "INNER JOIN skill_option so " +
                         "   on oc.id=so.option_category_id " +
                         "INNER JOIN skill_option_master som "  +
                         "   on som.id=so.id; "

                         ,new string[] { "som.id", "som.name", "som.search_enabled", "oc.id", "oc.name" });
```

...

```
private List<string> getMultiColumnListFromDB(string query, string[] columnNames)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

        con.Open();

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string strResult = "";
            foreach (string columnName in columnNames)
            {
                if (reader[columnName] == DBNull.Value) 
                    //If value is NULL, we assume yes/1
                    strResult = strResult + "1" + ";";
                else
                    strResult = strResult + reader[columnName].ToString() + ";";

            }
            result.Add(strResult.TrimEnd(';'));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

...I get: **System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Could not find specified column in results: som.id'** at Line: *if (reader[columnName] == DBNull.Value)*

As a test, I copied the query from the Exceptions window whilst debugging back into Workbench and it worked without any modifications required[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ68j.png). Simpler queries (without joins) work fine within my app. I appreciate my code isn't the most elegant but I can't get over [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ68j.png) above. How can that be?

Thanks

Comment: The colum names in the results don't contain the aliases (prefixes). Even in your screenshot, the column names don't include "`som.`" and such.

Comment: What are the column names and are the `string`s correctly passed?

Comment: ah. Is this where I must employ an 'as' ?

Comment: If you want them named as you have them in the array, yes, you would need to alias the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified SQL query to alias the column names:

```
SELECT som.id as 'som.id', som.name as 'som.name', som.search_enabled as 'som.search_enabled', oc.id as 'oc.id', oc.name as 'oc.name'
FROM option_category oc
INNER JOIN skill_option so
   on oc.id=so.option_category_id
INNER JOIN skill_option_master som
   on som.id=so.id;
```

Comment: an easier way is to just remove the "som" prefix from your string array `columnNames`